# Nav goes off the screen but button doesn't

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parallax</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <br><br>
        </nav>
        <h2>One ring to rule them all</h2>
        <button>View Our Work</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
}
body
{
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    padding: 0;
}
h2
{
    font-family: "Kingthings Calligraphica";
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30%;
}
nav
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
nav div
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
nav div:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
button
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Result:
[image: screenshot]

Why does the nav go off the screen but the button doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's cause you use

```
width:100%;
```

and

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

which equals to

```
100% + 2px;
```

than you also add `padding`

and it just adds to the math.

This will work: http://jsbin.com/vubug/2/edit

```
nav{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

**To let the browser do the math you can also use the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) CSS property. <sup>(*2014 still experimental)</sup>**

Also worth to note: action elements (`input`, `button` etc) act differently across browsers and even OS. The padding applied to a 100% width `button` is applied inwards, while applied to a 100% width block level DIV element it acts outwards adding to the set width.

One of the logic reasons is that you cannot have `block-level` elements inside the `<button></button>` (and have a valid markup) that will allow you to use that element's `padding` instead, so browsers try to compensate that applying the `padding` in the inner `button`'s space. [TEST CASE](http://jsbin.com/stackoverflow/1/edit)

### Using CSS3 `box-sizing: border-box ;`

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tobop/1/edit)

```
  <div id="widthAuto">DIV {width: auto;}</div> <!-- DESIRED -->
  <div id="width100">DIV {width: 100%;}</div> <!-- OVERFLOWS -->

  <div id="fixed">DIV {position:fixed;}</div> <!-- LOOSES WIDTH -->
  <div id="fixed_width100">DIV {position:fixed; width:100%;}</div> <!-- OVERFLOWS --> 
  <div id="fixed_width100_boxSizing">DIV {position:fixed; width:100%; box-sizing: border-box;}</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  background:#ddd;
  border:10px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  font-family:monospace;
}
div[id^=fi]{border-color:blue}


#widthAuto{
  width:auto;
}
#width100{
  width:100%; 
}

#fixed{
  position:fixed; /* Not in flow and looses the "auto" width :( */ 
  /*just for preview*/ top:200px;  
}
#fixed_width100{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;    /* same issue as #width100 */
  /*just for preview*/ top:300px;  
}
#fixed_width100_boxSizing{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*just for preview*/ top:400px;  
}
```

---

### Simplest solution

Or simply use the `fixed` element as a 100% width dummy wrapper and apply padding, border, whatever you need to an inner element. That's the way I do.

Comment: Removed it and still the same result.

Comment: @V0R73X you cannot have both width 100% and the border, cause your right border will go off.

Comment: but the button has the same style applied to it

Comment: I see. So what's the correct way to implement this? (this = 100% width nav bar with borders)

Comment: @V0R73X edited my answer. Hope will help to understand. Your main issue it that you need a fixed element but with padding. The other solution would be to have an inner element (with padding) inside a simplistic fixed element with 100% width.